# error C2059: syntax error: '}' C++

Tags: c++, syntax, label, goto

```
void walka(Postac p, Przeciwnik e, int walkaa)
{
    if (p.szybkosc < 0)
    {
        p.szybkosc = 0;
    }
walka:
    walkaa = p.szybkosc - e.szybkosc;
    if (walkaa > 0)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Zadajesz " << p.sila << " obrażeń." << endl << endl;
            e.zycie -= p.sila;
            cout << "Życie: " << p.zycie << " Życie przeciwnika: " << e.zycie << endl << endl;
            if (e.zycie <= 0)
            {
                cout << "Wygrałeś!" << endl;
                goto koniecwalki;
            }
            walkaa -= e.szybkosc;
        } while (walkaa > 0);
        goto walka;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Otrzymujesz " << e.sila << " obrażeń." << endl << endl;
            p.zycie -= e.sila;
            cout << "Życie: " << p.zycie << " Życie przeciwnika: " << e.zycie << endl << endl;
            if (p.zycie <= 0)
            {
                cout << "Zostałeś pokonany." << endl;
                goto koniecwalki2;
            }
            walkaa += p.szybkosc;
        } while (walkaa < 0);
    }
    goto walka;
koniecwalki:
    cout << "Przegrana" << endl;
koniecwalki2:

}
```

1>Others.cpp(202): error C2059: syntax error: '}'

202nd line is the last curly bracket at the end of this function.
 I don't know why I'm getting this error now. I had it earlier a few times but every time it was just random additional bracket which I had to remove.

Comment: Is there specific reason for using those `goto` jumps?

Comment: Could you please also give us the complete error message.

Comment: A hint: always program in English. Another hint: don't use goto in C++.

Comment: don't use goto. ever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax error means that you have to use a null statement after the label

```
koniecwalki2: ;
             ^^^
}
```

That is it is a statement that can be labeled (in C++ declarations are also statements while in C declarations are not statements).

Take into account that it is a bad idea to use `goto` statements. That makes the code difficult to read and modify.

Comment: Not to mention `goto` statements making the code harder to debug and possible security issues that might arise.

Comment: @Immac It seems that you did not work at IBM. They would explain very quickly that there is nothing bad in using the goto statement.:)